# Why is ratio of number of field lines same as ratio of charges?

Tags: electricity

I have read this in a lot of books, but never found proof about it. So, I tried using gauss law But my teacher says that the proportionality constant would be different in both cases as they both produce a different effect on each other. He also said that flux is proportional to field lines perpendicular to the area element of the Gaussian surface and not on field lines in any direction intersecting with the gaussian surface. I am a bit doubtful.

Proof :
Let $t$ be the proportionality constant between flux and field line.

If we take a gaussian surface surrounding just $q_1$. we get the flux $$\phi_1 =  q_1/\epsilon\ .$$
Similarly, flux through gaussian surface surrounding $q_2$ is $$\phi_2 = q_2/\epsilon\ .$$

Let the number of lines originating or terminating at $q_1$ be $N_1$ and at $q_2$ be $N_2$.

$$t N_1 = q_1/\epsilon$$
$$t N_2 = q_2/\epsilon $$

$N_1/N_2 = q_1/q_2$. Hence proved.

Comment: Hello! It is preferable to use MathJax (LaTeX) to display formulas. You can find a tutorial at [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Please [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: why is mathjax not working

Comment: You need to put "$"s before and after your formula, as ProfRob edited.

Comment: It worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The number of field lines one draws is just a convention, to suggest the field is stronger if the lines are more dense. Theoretically, they give only the direction of the force, so you can draw as many or as few as you want.Of cause you cannot start a line in the middle of nowhere, so they start at a charge or a charged body.When you see a picture of fieldlines starting  for example at a sphere , it just says, the sphere is charged , you wiill nit know if the charge is 1As or 10^-6 As.

Comment: Trula, Thank you for your answer, I get that number of field lines one draws is to suggests the field is stronger if the lines are denser. I am asking that if the RATIO of the field lines is dependent only on the charges by the relation I tried to prove.

Comment: You usually draw field lines in 2d, on a paper, if you want them proportional to the charge then only in 3d. In any picture I have ever seen, th number of drawn lines had nothing to do  withe the amount of charges they started of.

Comment: Have you read university physics , or serway physics